# ruby on rails search form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to RoR and I've managed to make a basic search form but keep getting errors when trying to expand the search tags (name).. I have a model with various data (location, website, email, telephone) and was wondering how I can add these to my current search code.

`/models/ciir.rb`

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
  else
    find(:all)
  end
end
```

`static_pages_controller.rb`

```
def home
  @ciirs = Ciir.search(params[:search])
end
```

`/home.html.erb`

```
<%= form_tag ciirs_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag " Search Database Records ", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

When clicking the submit button (no search terms) the url is:

```
ciirs?utf8=✓&search=
```

but when modifying the name condition to something like 'website' the url changes to

```
ciirs?utf8=✓&search=&commit=+Search+Database+Records+ –
```

Comment: What are the errors you are getting?

Comment: If I change the 'name' condition to website (and the corresponding name in the other files) the url changes from:

ciirs?utf8=✓&search=random   (to)
ciirs?utf8=✓&search=&commit=+Search+Database+Records+

Comment: have you consider using ransack or, for more agressive search, thinking sphinx ?

Answer (score 6):

Since you mentioned you are new to RoR, I must share the way I learned RoR was reading, using and analyzing one issue at a time. I would suggest you to take a look at following points one at a time and try & learn how RoR treats them and how these fit your question:

1. How `form_tag` works?
2. How `text_field_tag` works?
3. Once you have understood `form_tag`, difference between `text_field_tag` and `f.text_field`?
4. How `params` objects are created, and it uses names of form controls?
5. How and when to use `GET` and/or `POST` form methods? Inadvertently, what are different types of method and when to use them?
6. How `URL` are used in the `form_tag` and what components are they made of?
7. Sprinkle a bit of knowledge of `Ruby` language by learning between `Array`s and `Hash`es? In fact, learn `Ruby` as much as you can.

Answering your question,

`/home.html.erb`

```
<%= form_tag "/static_pages/home", :method => 'post' do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag "search[name]", params.has_key?("search") && params[:search].has_key?("name") ? params[:search][:name] : "" %>
    <%= submit_tag " Search Database Records " %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

`/models/ciir.rb`

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    find(:all, :conditions => ["name LIKE '%?%'", search[:name]])
  else
    find(:all)
  end
end
```

So I modified your form, and told RoR about `search` `params` containing data for `name`.

`params` is a `Hash` (which is a `key-value pair`) having key named `search`, which further is a `Hash` having key named `name`.

The same principle is followed in the model code. We passed the `Hash` of key `search` to the function and in there, used the value of key named `name`.

I also updated the url in `form_tag`, to point it to home action of your controller. Assuming that you have added it to your `routes.rb` file, it usually follows the pattern `controller_name/action_name` or the function name `action_name_controller_name_path` or `action_name_controller_name_url`. Run `rake routes` command at your root directory to list out all paths in your application.

Also note, I used `POST` method instead of original `GET`. You may wish to use `GET` here, so please change it back.

I hope this works.

Comment: The code posted produces the following error:

undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Okay, let's go step-by-step debugging it, as I posted it from top of my head. Could you post on which line it is throwing this error? If I assume correctly, it must be the line in the `erb` file. I have edited my post.

Comment: `11:   <h2>
12: <%= form_tag "/static_pages/home", :method => 'get' do %>
13:   <p>
14:     <%= text_field_tag "search[name]", params[:search][:name] %>
15:     <%= submit_tag " Search Database Records " %>
16:   </p>
17: <% end %>`

Comment: I assumed that was the case and I have edited my post. Please check the line containing `text_field_tag`. We needed to check if `params` has key `search`, and `search` has key `name`.

Comment: It works but only seems to take me the the /ciirs/index.html.erb page. For example, company A is called accounting and company B is called bakery. When I type accounting into the search it displays both companies, whereas I only want it to display accounting.

Answer (score 0):

I found no error in your code. the url changed to `ciirs?utf8=✓&search=&commit=+Search+Database+Records+` is normal. `submit_tag` generates a `button` named "commit" defaultly, it will be parsed in the params. I see you add :name => nil , it will fix the problem, the other part of your code needn't to be modified. I copied your code and tested it, it ran smoothly.